# How to upgrade to Twitter REST API v1.1 in search for Reader case

Tags: rest, search, twitter, rss-reader

I used to use the following url in Google reader to track particular words activity on twitter in my reader.
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=WORDHERE

But 1) Google decided to close its reader 2) twitter decided to deprecate their REST API v1.0.

Hence I now use http://theoldreader.com/ (which is pretty cool btw) and I'd like to know how to upgrade my twitter query/url to make it work with my new reader.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Can you give us more information / code examples?

Comment: There is nothing more than this sorry if it is not clear enough. In Google Reader I used to subscribe to twitter word listening just with the provided url, more precisely for listening to the usage of word "WORD" in twitter I just used to subscribe to "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=WORD"   I'd like to be able to have the same feature now under http://theoldreader.com/